# How to translate Carbon 1.32 in Laravel 5.7 - Enviroment Docker(Laradock)

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I need to translate carbon:

I've already tried to import all translation packeges and setting location doesn't work.I've already changed the location in config/app.php and used php setlocation functions.

In Carbons doc the diffforhumans worked very well, but  the day of the week and month doesn't worked.

I've also tried  to install the translation package on docker(Laradock)

Sorry about my english! :)

Examples :

```
$boringLanguage = 'en_Boring';
$translator = \Carbon\Translator::get($boringLanguage);
$translator->setTranslations([
    'day' => ':count boring day|:count boring days',
]);
// as this language starts with "en_" it will inherit from the locale "en"

$date1 = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
$date2 = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 4, 4, 0, 0);

echo $date1->locale($boringLanguage)->diffForHumans($date2); // 3 boring days before

$translator->setTranslations([
    'before' => function ($time) {
        return '['.strtoupper($time).']';
    },
]);

echo $date1->locale($boringLanguage)->diffForHumans($date2);

------------------------------------------------------------

Carbon::setLocale('pt_BR');


_____________________________________________________________


setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));
        exit();

____________________________________________________________________
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');  
        print ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A'));
        exit();
```

Comment: Have you installed the required locales within the system itself? PHP relies on them at system level to be utilised within the set_locale() calls.

Comment: Yes.
When I run locale -a, I've a list with all packages.